# Visual studio git commands

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio git for some time and trying to work with git commands now

I am wondering what are the underlying git commands for the below commands in Visual Studio

[image: Git Commands in visual Studio]

Does anyone have any idea of what the underlying commands are?

Let's say I want to commit with the message, I am trying

```
git commit -a "sample message"
```

However, it is throwing an error saying that my branch is ahead of the master branch by 4 commits.

But if I click on Commit All, it is committing. What am I missing?

Comment: As far as your command goes : use `-m` if you want to pass a commit message from the command line : `git commit -a -m "sample message"` ; or don't provide anything and type your message in the text editor that opens : `git commit -a`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 2 commands.

```
1. git add .
2. git commit -m "sample message"
```

So, you wrote some your code, then you need to execute command: " git add . " - stages your changes to the "temporary storage" before do commit.
Then, you can do simple commit via: " git commit -m "sample message" ".
And it is done.

Best regards

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's concern. The question was regarding the behavior of Visual Studio's git options.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick I gave an example of commit but I would like to know the behavior and how other commands work